# unable to display javascript on my website

Tags: javascript, html

i have designed a website. it is now live with http://innovakota.6te.net

I have used some java script on this for sliding the pics. it is running good on localhost. but when i am running on server, the slider is not working. 
The javascript code is as follow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $().piroBox({
            my_speed: 400, //animation speed
            bg_alpha: 0.1, //background opacity
            slideShow : false, // true == slideshow on, false == slideshow off
            slideSpeed : 4, //slideshow duration in seconds(3 to 6 Recommended)
            close_all : '.piro_close,.piro_overlay'// add class .piro_overlay(with comma)if you want overlay click close piroBox

    });
});
</script>
```

I have tried it on three hostings but the same problem is coming. i am attaching the local host snapshot also.
[image]

Please help me guys

Comment: The file you uploaded to server is severely corrupted. Just look at http://innovakota.6te.net/lib/jquery.custom.js Also, any plugin that works with `$()` is terrible and should not be used.

Comment: @Esailija would you mind explaining a little more why expanding the jQuery object methods (`$.fn`) is terrible? Got me curious there.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté `$()` returns an empty jQuery object. You expect jQuery methods to operate on the wrapped DOM elements, but that's not the case if the plugin works on an empty jQuery object.

Comment: @Esailija Oh my bad, when you mentioned `$()` I thought you meant the wrapped objects inside the given jQuery object and not a literally empty object. I should take a second look in the code. Thanks `=]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to clean your jquery.custom.js

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: @Rohitashv re-upload the file, if it's still with illegal characters, save it with UTF-8 encoding and re-up it.

Comment: Perhaps there was a problem during transfer to the remote server.

Comment: thanks guys. plz can u help me one more thing. that if I want to protect my files, then how can I do??

Comment: What did you mean by "protect my files" ?

Comment: Protect, as in, make them un-downloadable? It's simple. Don't upload them. No, but seriously, everything that can be displayed can be copied - one way or another.

Comment: Don't put them on the internet.

Comment: Also if you meant protect the JS code, it's possible to compress, uglify, obfuscate and base64 it but it will always be available to the end-user and those determined to hack it will achieve it. It shouldn't be much of a problem as long as you have a sturdy server-side security. Now obviously, if you ever create a big plugin or something, you can patent it and sue those who copy it without the right to use it -- there are people whom that, even though I'd personally prefer to see a free internet and help developing a brighter future for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Garbage in the JS file (http://innovakota.6te.net/lib/jquery.custom.js) - you need to take a look at it

਀�
//Wave slider call ----------------------------------------------------਀樀儀甀攀爀礀⠀搀漀挀甀洀攀渀琀⤀⸀爀攀愀搀礀⠀昀甀渀挀琀椀漀渀⠀⤀ 笀�
    jQuery('.waveshow').nivoSlider({਀ऀऀ攀昀昀攀挀琀㨀✀猀氀椀挀攀䐀漀眀渀✀Ⰰ�
        slices:15,਀ऀऀ愀渀椀洀匀瀀攀攀搀㨀㄀　　　Ⰰ�
        pauseTime:5000,਀ऀऀ搀椀爀攀挀琀椀漀渀一愀瘀㨀琀爀甀攀Ⰰ ⼀⼀一攀砀琀 ☀ 倀爀攀瘀�
        directionNavHide:true, //Only show on hover਀ऀऀ挀漀渀琀爀漀氀一愀瘀㨀昀愀氀猀攀Ⰰ ⼀⼀㄀Ⰰ㈀Ⰰ㌀⸀⸀⸀�
        keyboardNav:true, //Use left & right arrows਀ऀऀ瀀愀甀猀攀伀渀䠀漀瘀攀爀㨀琀爀甀攀Ⰰ ⼀⼀匀琀漀瀀 愀渀椀洀愀琀椀漀渀 眀栀椀氀攀 栀漀瘀攀爀椀渀最�
        manualAdvance:false, //Force manual transitions਀ऀऀ挀愀瀀琀椀漀渀伀瀀愀挀椀琀礀㨀　⸀㠀Ⰰ ⼀⼀唀渀椀瘀攀爀猀愀氀 挀愀瀀琀椀漀渀 漀瀀愀挀椀琀礀�
        beforeChange: function(){},਀ऀऀ愀昀琀攀爀䌀栀愀渀最攀㨀 昀甀渀挀琀椀漀渀⠀⤀笀紀Ⰰ�
        slideshowEnd: function(){} //Triggers after all slides have been shown਀ऀ紀⤀㬀�
});਀�
਀�